# Change to new page (not http://asdasd.com, my own page) - javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

I know how to change to a new window and im doing it like this:

```
window.replace(myURL);
```

However, it doesn't do anything when i put "home.html"

How can i make it go to my new page?

Answer (score 1):

Why do not you use:

```
window.location.replace("home.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.replace("home.html");`

Answer (score 1):

This will open a newpage

```
window.open("home.html")
```

This will result loading a new page in same window

```
window.location.href="home.html";
```

Also you can use  assign to loads a new document.

```
window.location.assign("home.html")
```